# eclipse java import organizing

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

in test classes I have the following import

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

when I do organize import via ctrl + shift + o then it automatically changes to following

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
```

How can I configure eclipse not to do it ?
PS: I only want junit imports not be handled in that way

=============

I added a save action to remove unused imports. [properties -> java editor -> save actions]
so everytime I save unused imports are removed (since I used ctrl + shift + o mainly to remove unused imports this looks like a way forward..)

Comment: Don't press "CTRL + SHIFT + O" then.

Comment: :D @silverback. Whats wrong if eclipse does this. It's general practice to import only what is needed.

Comment: That is the correct approach. But the OP doesn't want it that way. :)

Comment: The OP also wants to limit it to junit packages. Talk about wasting time being a control freak..

Comment: @silverback thx for the hint.. seems like save actions will do the trick for me

Answer (score 8):

Change the number of static imports to 1

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Under Window, Preferences, Java, Code Style, Organize Imports there's an option called "Number of static imports needed for .*" - set that to 1. (Another way to find it quickly is just to type "static" into the search box in preferences.)

Note that this will mean that hitting Ctrl-Shift-O will always turn any static imports into an static import-on-demand form, which may not be what you want. If you have separate projects for test and non-test code, you could configure it on a per project basis.

Personally I'd just live with the explicit imports - I usually end up with static imports by starting off with the class-qualified call, and then hitting Ctrl-Shift-M on the method name to import it statically.

Comment: @Karna: I was thinking about doing that, but figured the text would be enough - and it gave me more time to write explanatory text :)

Comment: @DevBlanked: No, but I've given a few other options in my answer.